# getting this error in unity (2018.4.6) error CS0103: The name 'linkApp' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have imported a game from unity 2017.4.16 to unity 2018.4.6 and I'm getting this error

```
Assets\Scripts\Controllers\GetCoinController.cs(103,24): error CS0103: 
The name 'linkApp' does not exist in the current context
```

Code that seems relevant is:

```
public void RateButton() 
{ 
    SoundController.sound.Click (); 
    // string linkApp; 
    #if UNITY_ANDROID 
    linkApp = "play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + Application.identifier; 
    #elif UNITY_IOS 
    linkApp = "itunes.apple.com/us/app/candy-fruit-juice/…";
    #endif Application.OpenURL (linkApp); PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("rate", 1); 
    PlayerPrefs.Save (); 
    rate.SetActive (false); 
    AdsControl.instance.addCoins.AddReward (true, AddCoins.rateOrLogin);
}
```

Comment: This is unreadable in comments. Use [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57543061/edit) if you want to add content to your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like someone(?) accidentally commented out the declaration of `string linkApp;`. Remove the two forward slashes and the code should compile fine.